# Infinite loop when updating meteor collection within forEach

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm creating a site that allows users to vote on things they like to influence their order in a list ( like reddit ).

When I iterate over my collection using forEach and then try to update each entry based on the index of the sorted results it just ends up in an infinite loop and my app crashes!

Any help would be great, code is below.

```
MyList.find( {}, sort: votes: -1 ).forEach ( item, index ) ->

    MyList.update item._id, $set: rank: index
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where does this code run? It's a wild guess, but it seems like you're on the wrong end of the reactive computation blade.

Comment: This code runs on the client after all my collections are ready. @Kyll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop some code from causing re-runs, use `Tracker.nonreactive` (http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive)

Like this:

```
Tracker.nonreactive ->
  MyList.find( {}, sort: votes: -1 ).forEach ( item, index ) ->
    MyList.update item._id, $set: rank: index
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. Didn't work initially but when I moved the Tracker.nonreactive function above the MyList.find() function it worked perfectly. Thanks!